# Cannot open Android Project correctly - Android view contains oly Java folder

Tags: android-studio

When I open an existing project, I don't see the normal hierarchy in the "Android View".

I have a Project that contains many folders and also gradle files. The "Project view" shows many folders and files. When I change to the "Android View" I expect the gradle Scripts and the res folder (like [this one](http://unhackathon.org/springboard-projects/img/filestructure.png)) but there is only an empty Java folder.

Android Studio told me, I should migrate the project to gradle, but the linked information shows basic information about Android Studio (https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html). The Project is already a gradle project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened if you click `File --> Open` and then find your project. (but open that one with android icon, not just folder icon).

Comment: argh dumb failure, you were right, I opened the wrog folder. It also had an icon but I needed to choose one that was deeper in the hierarchy. thanks!